# How To Looping Foreach in Laravel

Tags: laravel

i'm try to foreach inside the foreach to get the count data with this code

**Controller.php**

```
$jadwals = DB::table('tb_jadwal')->get();
foreach ($jadwals as $key => $jadwal) {
    $tgl = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->tgl));
    $cek_tiket = array();
    $cek_tiket = DB::table('tb_tiket')
            ->select(DB::raw('count( distinct id_tiket) as jumlah_kapasitas'))
            ->where('Tgl_Berangkat', '=', "'$tgl'")
            ->where('id_jadwal', '=', $jadwal->id_jadwal)
            ->get();
    $jadwals[$key]->jumlah_kapasitas = $cek_tiket;
}
```

**view.blade.php**

```
@foreach($cek_tiket as $cek_tiket)
    <?php
    if ($cek_tiket->jumlah_kapasitas <= 70) {
        echo "There data";
        dd($cek_tiket);
    }
    ?>
@endforeach
```

but the result of dd is 0

Comment: use `other name in foreach like $cek_tiket as $cek` and use `$cek inside loop`

Comment: **Suggestion:** You should use the eloquent model with relationship for better performance. Or alternate option is to use the join with your query.

Comment: I would advice you to take a loot at [Laravel Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent) and [Laravel Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections).

Comment: `$cek_ticket` in your Controller should be pluralised to `$cek_tickets` otherwise you risk die dumping the original variable.